# How to stop a FitNesse SuiteSetup from showing yellow

Tags: fitnesse

[FitNesse](http://fitnesse.org)'s SuiteSetup page is shown as yellow instead of green in the test results. This can be corrected by adding a dummy test that has at least one green cell. But surely a setup page shouldn't require an actual test cell? Is there a fix for this?

Using FitNesse 20111026.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug.  I've added an issue. http://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/issues/80